# How can a method accept java.sql.timestamp when the definition of the method says that it accepts java.sql.date as a parameter?

Tags: java

I am working on a project where we have an existing util class for dates. There is an method there which accepts `java.sql.Date` as a parameter but when while developing I pass a `java.sql.Timestamp` object, it is working fine. One thing can be that the Timestamp is the child class of Date. I need some clarity on this

Comment: Did you have a look at the source of `Timestamp`? Hint: `public class Timestamp extends java.util.Date`.

Comment: You just need to look at the _javadoc_ for class [java.sql.Timestamp](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/sql/Timestamp.html).

Comment: Everybody please notice that the OP says the method accepts `java.sql.Date`, not `java.util.Date`. `java.sql.Timestamp` does **not** extend `java.sql.Date`.

Comment: As mentioned by @RealSkeptic, `java.sql.Timestamp` is not a subclass of `java.sql.Date` so it shouldn't be accepted if param is type `java.sql.Date`. Are you sure your method doesn't have parameter type `java.util.Date` instead (which `Timestamp` is a subclass of)?

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. This is simply not possible. Maybe you're confusing `java.sql.Date` and `java.util.Date`, or maybe there is an overload (eg in a superclass) that accepts `java.util.Date`.

Comment: I checked again, bad documentation at method level. It accepts java.util.Date but in the method level comments it was specified that it accepts java.sql.Date. 
I guess documentation needs to be improved here also. Thanks everyone for your answers.

Answer (score -1):

yep, heredity

```
java.lang.Object
   |
   +----java.util.Date
           |
           +----java.sql.Timestamp
```

Comment: The OP says the method accepts `java.sql.Date`, not `java.util.Date`.